# gnuplot: multiplot zooming

Tags: c++, graph, plot, zooming, gnuplot

I am searching for a zoom option in multiplot in gnuplot. I am able to do zooming in normal gnuplot using ***set mouse zoomjump***. But it does not work in multiplot. Any ideas about how  I can zoom in multiplot? I am sending commands from my C++ program to gnuplot.

Thanks

Comment: You could use a workaround. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/76657921/7295599 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/62148384/7295599 which can be adapted for earlier gnuplot versions (at least for >=4.6.0, March 2012).

Answer (score 4):

You can only zoom in on the most recent plot in the multiplot.  See this quote from the gnuplot manual in the Mouse section:

> Mousing is not available inside multiplot mode. When multiplot is completed using unset multiplot, then the mouse will be turned on again but acts only on the most recent plot within the multiplot (like replot does).

Comment: Thanks..yeah.. I tried that. So There is not zooming function available for mulitplots till now.