gnuplot 6.0: unset shared x-axis in multiplot
It seems gnuplot 6.0 now assumes shared x-axis by default (instead of optionally).
Is there a possibility to turn this off (beyond setting xrange manually)?
Here is an example to understand the current behaviour
set multiplot layout 2,1
plot "+" us 0:(sin(0.1*$0))
plot "+" us ($0+1000):(sin(0.1*$0))
unset multiplot


When zooming in the lower panel, the data in the upper panel not visible anymore.


In gnuplot versions prior to 6.0 you could not zoom, pan, or replot inside multiplots at all.  Now you can, but as you found the behavior does not always match expectations or preferences.
Think about what happens after a multiplot if you reset the xrange from the command line and then re-issue all the plot commands. Version 6 automates this process; the replot command causes the program to re-execute the original set of plot commands starting from the new setting for xrange and any other settings that were changed. The mouse pan/zoom operations work similarly.
Support for mouse interactions in a multiplot are a work in progress.  Please consider submitting a feature request through the project web site with suggestions for how to improve it. What new commands or mouse options would would you like to see?

Ok, I see. Indeed, I asked for a shared x-axis in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148384. I expected this to be an option in multiplot.
When zooming, only the last plot panel should be redrawn.
Another question: When zooming prior v6.0, it replotted only the last plot, but again to the full window. Can this behaviour be recovered?

In many cases saying refresh rather than replot will act that way. The main caveat I can think of is that refresh will always re-use the currently stored data points.  So this would not work if your intent was to modify the last plot to show changes to the data in a file modified since the last plot.

Another thought: you could use evaluate(GPVAL_LAST_PLOT) instead of refresh.  Either of these plays nicely with remultiplot in this situation.  You can alternate between them as you like; remultiplot will recreate the entire previous panel, refresh or evaluate(GPVAL_LAST_PLOT) will redraw only the final subplot from the panel while preserving the commands necessary to invoke remultiplot again.

I tried first to overwrite $GPVAL_LAST_MULTIPLOT with eval GPVAL_LAST_PLOT after unset multiplot. So this gets called automatically when zooming, but behaves fragile and yields warning: Cannot find or open file after some zoom actions. But overwriting with refresh seems more robust. Thx.

Is there actually a solution to prevent zooming in the first plot using at least xrange? To me even this seems not possible.

Using some of @Ethan's suggestions, here is a list implementing various behaviours

shared axis
nothings needs to be done
zoom only last plot; reject first plot (behaviour as in v5)

set multiplot layout 2,1
plot "+" us 0:(sin(0.1*$0))
plot "+" us ($0+1000):(sin(0.1*$0))
unset multiplot

# overwrite MULTIPLOT to keep only the last plot
$GPVAL_LAST_MULTIPLOT << EOD
refresh
EOD


zoom last plot, keep first plot
This uses dummy plots to capture the zoom rect. Likely inefficient, but working to some degree.

set xrange [*:*]
set yrange [*:*]

# initial plot to initialise ranges
plot "+" us ($0+1000):(sin(0.1*$0))
zoom_plot = GPVAL_LAST_PLOT

set multiplot layout 2,1

# two dummy plots; first to get zoom rect from last plot, second to fill remaining panel
refresh
xa = GPVAL_X_MIN
xb = GPVAL_X_MAX
ya = GPVAL_Y_MIN
yb = GPVAL_Y_MAX
plot 0
clear
clear

# ranges must be hardcoded (otherwise they become the zoom rect)
set xrange [0:100]
set yrange [-2:2]
plot "+" us 0:(2*sin(0.1*$0))

set xrange [xa:xb]
set yrange [ya:yb]
eval zoom_plot

unset multiplot

