# gnuplot and multiplot: zooming works only for last plot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm creating a multiplot in gnuplot and I would like to zoom in a region on one of the plots. I use the mouse to do so but what happens after I zoom in, is that the multiplots disappear and I get the last plot zoomed in the same region i wanted to zoom initially at the other plot.

The following figures show what I'm dealing with

[image]

[image]

My code is the following

```
# visual commands
set terminal qt size 1300,1200

#---Axes
set format y "%.2f"

low_energy  = real(system('awk -F = ''{if (NR == 9) print $2 }'' 149Sm.sh'))
high_energy = real(system('awk -F = ''{if (NR == 10) print $2 }'' 149Sm.sh'))
set xrange [low_energy:high_energy]

#---Grid
set grid ytics mytics xtics mxtics  # draw lines for each ytics and mytics
set grid                            # enable the grid

#---Make the plot aesthetically better
set border lw 2
set key at graph 0.99, 0.99
set key font "Helvetica Bold,14"
set key box lw 1
set log x


set multiplot layout 5,1 columns
# Let's plot the sucker!

#Thin transmission
set title "Thin transmission"
set yrange [-0.1:1.2]
plot 'results/Sm149tThinFinal.asc' using ($1):($2):($3) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149tThinFinal.asc' using ($1):($4) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"

#Thick transmission
set title "Thick transmission"
set yrange [-0.1:1.2]
plot 'results/Sm149tThickFinal.asc' using ($1):($2):($3) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149tThickFinal.asc' using ($1):($4) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"

#J4 capture
set title "J4 capture"
set autoscale y
plot 'results/Sm149cJ4Final.asc' using ($1):($2):($3) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149cJ4Final.asc' using ($1):($4) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"

#J3 capture
set title "J3 capture"
set autoscale y
plot 'results/Sm149cJ3Final.asc' using ($1):($2):($2) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149cJ3Final.asc' using ($1):($4) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"

#Total capture
set title "Total capture"
set xlabel "Incident neutron energy (eV)" font "Helvetica Bold,14" offset 0,0,0
set autoscale y
plot 'results/Sm149cFinal.asc' using ($1):($2):($3) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149cFinal.asc' using ($1):($4) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"
   

unset multiplot
```

Any idea on how to zoom in on individual multiplots?

**EDIT 1**

I modified my code according to the answer provided in [Interactive multiplot with shared x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148384/interactive-multiplot-with-shared-x-axis)

```
# visual commands
set terminal qt size 1300,1200

#---Axes
set format y "%.2f"


low_energy  = real(system('awk -F = ''{if (NR == 9) print $2 }'' 149Sm.sh'))
high_energy = real(system('awk -F = ''{if (NR == 10) print $2 }'' 149Sm.sh'))
set xrange [low_energy:high_energy]

#---Grid
set grid ytics mytics xtics mxtics  # draw lines for each ytics and mytics
set grid                            # enable the grid

#---Make the plot aesthetically better
set border lw 2
set key at graph 0.99, 0.99
set key font "Helvetica Bold,14"
set key box lw 1
set log x

cond=1; while(cond) {
   set yrange [*:*]

set multiplot layout 5,1 columns
# Let's plot the sucker!

#Thin transmission
set title "Thin transmission"
set yrange [-0.1:1.2]
plot 'results/Sm149tThinFinal.asc' using ($1):($2):($3) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149tThinFinal.asc' using ($1):($4) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"

#Thick transmission
set title "Thick transmission"
set yrange [-0.1:1.2]
plot 'results/Sm149tThickFinal.asc' using ($1):($2):($3) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149tThickFinal.asc' using ($1):($4) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"

#J4 capture
set title "J4 capture"
set autoscale y
plot 'results/Sm149cJ4Final.asc' using ($1):($2):($3) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149cJ4Final.asc' using ($1):($4) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"

#J3 capture
set title "J3 capture"
set autoscale y
plot 'results/Sm149cJ3Final.asc' using ($1):($2):($2) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149cJ3Final.asc' using ($1):($4) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"

#Total capture
set title "Total capture"
set xlabel "Incident neutron energy (eV)" font "Helvetica Bold,14" offset 0,0,0
set autoscale y
plot 'results/Sm149cFinal.asc' using ($1):($2):($3) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149cFinal.asc' using ($1):($5) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"

   unset multiplot

   pause mouse button1,button2
   cond = MOUSE_KEY != 2   # exit on middle click

}
```

I sort of works. The issue is that when I use the mouse to zoom in, the multiplot disappears, then the last plots appears zoomed-in so I have to close the window to see the multiplots zoomed in. Same when I used keyboard commands to unzoom or switch from log to lin axes.

The desired behavior is to zoom on one plot , zoom all graphs with identical x and keeping y-autoscale.

What's happening i.e. when trying to unset log x-axis is:

1. Shift + L
2. The last plot appears on the multiplot wondow anf the x-axes is still log
3. Again Shift + L
4. The x-axis becomes linear
5. Left mouse click
6. The multiplot appears with all x axes, linear.

Comment: Not possible.  Gnuplot only only maintains sufficient state and context to reproduce the most recent "plot" or "splot" command.  That's what the "replot" command does.  If you want to recreate a series of plots, inside or outside a multiplot, you need to replay the command sequence that generated them. Since "zoom" is just a "replot with new axis ranges", only the most recent plot can be zoomed.

Comment: It is somehow possible.... see https://stackoverflow.com/q/62148384/7295599  if you have difficulties to adapt it to your concrete needs, edit your question and we will try to find a solution.

Comment: @Thanos It seems your x-axes are identical for all sub-plots. When zooming in, do you want to zoom in on x-axes for all sub-plots or additionally in y-axis of the selected plot as well? Do still want to see all subplots or just the selected plot? Could you please describe your desired zooming result in more detail?

Comment: @theozh I used Friedrich -- Слава Україні mouse answer. It sort of works; see edited question.

Comment: @Thanos yes, that's the workaround I would use as well. But I don't yet understand the issue you have with it. Which version of gnuplot are you running?

Comment: @theozh I'm using Version 5.2 patchlevel 8

Comment: @Thanos please describe your desired zooming behaviour. For example, (1) zoom all graphs with identical x and keeping y-autoscale or (2) zoom-in just the selected graph with x- and y-zoom and return with mouse-click to multiplot overview. There are many different possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script below is modified and complemented from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62170512/7295599) and can certainly be further optimized and adapted to your needs. Also check `help mouse variables`.

**Script:** (tested with gnuplot 5.2.8 and wxt terminal)

```
### zoom for multiplot
reset session

# create some test data
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:(sin($1)):(10000*cos(2*$1)):(sin($1)+cos(2*$1)) w table
unset table

set lmargin 10
stop = 0
Lx   = 0    # no log x-axis

while (!stop) {
    set autoscale y
    
    set multiplot layout 3,1
        plot $Data u 1:2 w l lw 2 lc "red"
        plot $Data u 1:3 w l lw 2 lc "web-green"
        plot $Data u 1:4 w l lw 2 lc "web-blue"
    unset multiplot
    
    pause mouse button1,button2,keypress
    stop = MOUSE_KEY == 2   # exit on middle click
    if (MOUSE_KEY==97) { set autoscale x }
    if (MOUSE_KEY==108) {
        Lx=!Lx
        if (Lx==1) { set xrange[0:GPVAL_X_MAX]; set logscale x }
        else { unset logscale x }
    }
}
### end of script
```

**Result:** (screen capture from Win10, wxt terminal)

What I was doing:

- zooming-in with mouse
- pressing `l` for `set logscale x`, and `l` again for `unset logscale x`
- pressing `a` for `set autoscale x`
- ...

[image]