# Gnuplot and multiplot with windows

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot data versus a model in a multiplot. The idea is to zoom on one multiplot and get the other plots zoomed in. I am able to do this part.

The tricky bit is that I want another multiplot in another window that will be sitting next to the first one. The second serve as a comparison between the data and the model, therefore, when I zoom in one multiplot, in either window, I would like all multiplots in both windows to zoom in.

Any idea on how to do that?

Here's my code so far

```
# visual commands
set terminal qt size 1300,1200

#---Axes
#set xlabel "Incident neutron energy (eV)" font "Helvetica Bold,14" offset 0,0,0
#set ylabel "Transmission/cross section" font "Helvetica Bold,14" offset 0,0,0
#set tics font "Helvetica Bold, 14"
#set xtics offset 0,-0.5,0
#set ytics (-0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2)
#set format x "%.0t*10^{%S}"
#set format x "10^{%L}"
set format y "%.2f"
#set yrange [-0.1:1.2]


#col = 1
#row = 0
#stats 'datafile' every ::row::row using col nooutput
#value = STATS_min
#plot "datafile" using 2:(value/$1) w lp

low_energy  = real(system('awk -F = ''{if (NR == 9) print $2 }'' 149Sm.sh'))
high_energy = real(system('awk -F = ''{if (NR == 10) print $2 }'' 149Sm.sh'))
set xrange [low_energy:high_energy]

#---Grid
set grid ytics mytics xtics mxtics  # draw lines for each ytics and mytics
#set mytics 5                        # set the spacing for the mytics
#set mxtics 10                       # set the spacing for the mxtics
set grid                            # enable the grid

#---Make the plot aesthetically better
#set margin 5
#set bmargin 5
set border lw 2
set key at graph 0.99, 0.99
set key font "Helvetica Bold,14"
set key box lw 1
set log x
#set xrange[0.05:0.5]

cond=1; while(cond) {
   set yrange [*:*]

set multiplot layout 5,1 columns
# Let's plot the sucker!

#Thin transmission
set title "Thin transmission"
set yrange [-0.1:1.2]
plot 'results/Sm149_Thin_i_trans.lst' using ($1):($6):($7) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149_Thin_i_trans.lst' using ($1):($8) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"

#Thick transmission
set title "Thick transmission"
set yrange [-0.1:1.2]
plot 'results/Sm149_Thick_i_trans.lst' using ($1):($6):($7) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149_Thick_i_trans.lst' using ($1):($8) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"

#J3 capture
set title "J3 capture"
set autoscale y
plot 'results/Sm149_J3_i_capture.lst' using ($1):($2):($3) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149_J3_i_capture.lst' using ($1):($4) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"

#J4 capture
set title "J4 capture"
set autoscale y
plot 'results/Sm149_J4_i_capture.lst' using ($1):($2):($3) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149_J4_i_capture.lst' using ($1):($4) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"

#Total capture
set title "Total capture"
set xlabel "Incident neutron energy (eV)" font "Helvetica Bold,14" offset 0,0,0
set autoscale y
plot 'results/Sm149_sum_i_capture.lst' using ($1):($2):($3) with yerrorbars pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Experimental", 'results/Sm149_sum_i_capture.lst' using ($1):($4) with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red' title "SAMMY"

   unset multiplot

   pause mouse button1,button2
   cond = MOUSE_KEY != 2   # exit on middle click

}

#unset multiplot




# visual commands
set terminal qt 2 size 1300,1200

#---Axes
set format y "%.2f"

low_energy  = real(system('awk -F = ''{if (NR == 9) print $2 }'' 149Sm.sh'))
high_energy = real(system('awk -F = ''{if (NR == 10) print $2 }'' 149Sm.sh'))
set xrange [low_energy:high_energy]

#---Grid
set grid ytics mytics xtics mxtics  # draw lines for each ytics and mytics
set grid                            # enable the grid

#---Make the plot aesthetically better
set border lw 2
set key at graph 0.99, 0.99
set key font "Helvetica Bold,14"
set key box lw 1
set log x

cond=1; while(cond) {
   set yrange [*:*]

set multiplot layout 5,1 columns
# Let's plot the sucker!

#Thin transmission
set title "Thin transmission"
set yrange [-5:5]
plot 'results/Sm149_Thin_i_trans_res.lst' using ($1):($2) pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Residuals", 0 with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red'

#Thick transmission
set title "Thick transmission"
set yrange [-5:5]
plot 'results/Sm149_Thick_i_trans_res.lst' using ($1):($2) pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Residuals", 0 with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red'

#J3 capture
set title "J3 capture"
set yrange [-5:5]
plot 'results/Sm149_J3_i_capture_res.lst' using ($1):($2) pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Residuals", 0 with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red'

#J4 capture
set title "J4 capture"
set yrange [-5:5]
plot 'results/Sm149_J4_i_capture_res.lst' using ($1):($2) pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Residuals", 0 with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red'
#Total capture
set title "Total capture"
set xlabel "Incident neutron energy (eV)" font "Helvetica Bold,14" offset 0,0,0
set yrange [-5:5]
plot 'results/Sm149_sum_i_capture_res.lst' using ($1):($2) pt 7 ps 0.5 black title "Residuals", 0 with lines lw 3 lc rgb 'red'
   unset multiplot

   pause mouse button1,button2
   cond = MOUSE_KEY != 2   # exit on middle click

}
```

Comment: instead of two windows with two 5x1 multiplots, why not one window with a 5x2, multiplot?

Comment: @theozh Hmmm... That's probably not a bad idea!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare data and model why don't you plot them into the same plot? Then you can overlay the data and *really* compare.

Anyway. As you did in your example you can define several terminal windows. The zooming like in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76657921/7295599) works in both windows, however, as far as I can see, the mouse operations only work on the latest window, not on the first one.

You start your zooming rectangle with a right mouse-click. I noticed if you finish the zooming rectangle with a right mouse-click as well only the last window will be zoomed. However, if you finish the zooming with a left mouse-click both windows will be zoomed.
See the following minimal example as starting point for further tweaking.

**Script:**

```
### zooming in two multiplot windows
reset session

set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:(sin(x)):(sin(x)+2*cos(x)) w table
set table $Model
    plot '+' u 1:(sin(x)):(sin(x)+2*cos(x)) w table
unset table

stop = 0

while (!stop) {
    set autoscale y
    
    set term wxt 1 size 640,320
    set multiplot layout 2,1
        plot $Data u 1:2 w l lc "red" 
        plot $Data u 1:2 w l lc "blue"
    unset multiplot

    set term wxt 2 size 640,320
    set multiplot layout 2,1
        plot $Model u 1:2 w l dt 3 lc "red"
        plot $Model u 1:2 w l dt 3 lc "blue"
    unset multiplot

    pause mouse button1,button2,keypress
    stop = MOUSE_KEY==120                  # press x to stop
    if (MOUSE_KEY==97) { set autoscale x } # press a to autoscale x
}
### end of script
```

**Result:** (screen capture from two wxt terminals)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! The trouble is that I can only zoom on the second window. None of the controls (either mouse or keyboard) work on the first window. Also, to answer your question about the the windows: I have 5 sets of data so ideally I would indeed put a residual plot below the main plot but that will add up to 10 plots. I'm not sure if 10 plot will look nice in one window but I'm open to ideas!

Comment: @Thanos if you are comparing data with a model, wouldn't it be the best if you plot the two curves in the same plot, i.e. 5 plots but data and model (ideally exactly) on top of each other. Then you can really judge if your model fits your data well. This will be difficult if you have two plots side by side.

Comment: The data span across a big range so typically we plot the data, the model and below a plot with the residuals.

Comment: @Thanos hence, 3 windows with 5x1 multiplots or 1 window with a 5x3 multiplot ;-) ? Let me know if you need anything more to mark this question as answered.